# How to move the origin or mirror the coordinate system?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable, coordinates

Consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot table [
            x=grade,
            y=value,
        ] {
            grade   value
            1   8
            2   1
            3   0
            4   1
            5   2
            6   0
            7   0
            8   0
            9   0
            10  0
            11  0
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which will give

[image]

I need to have the coordinate origin on the bottom right and evolve to the left (but not as negative numbers!).

How could I achieve this globally? (since I got quite a bunch of plots to treat this way).

Comment: `\begin{axis}[x dir=reverse]`? Or rather `\pgfplotsset{compat=newest,x dir=reverse}` for global effect.

Comment: I thought it would easy like that but couldnt come up with it. thanks. would you turn it into an answer?

Comment: By sheer coincidence I had learned about the setting earlier today, otherwise I would probably not have gotten it that quickly (or at all).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
x dir=reverse
```

to reverse the 'growth' of the x axis.

To make the setting global use

```
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest,x dir=reverse}
```

[image]